# oracle find to first hyphens after last vertical bar

Tags: oracle, regular-expression, regex

oracle find to first hyphens after last vertical bar using REGEXP_REPLACE

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('sadsa|dd|g - g|hh|yyyyy - tttt - ooo', '.*(\|)(?!.*\|).*?\-{1}', '' ) FROM dual;
```

string input

```
 'sadsa|dd|g - g|hh|yyyyy - tttt - ooo'
```

expected output

```
'sadsa|dd|g - g|hh|yyyyy -'
```

this regex working on notepad++ but not on oracle

```
.*(\|)(?!.*\|).*?\-{1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table t (
  c varchar2(64)
);

insert into t values ('sadsa|dd|g - g|hh|yyyyy - tttt - ooo');
insert into t values ('sadsa|dd|g - g|hh|yyyyy - tttt | - ooo');
insert into t values ('sad -sa|dd|g - g|hh|yy yyy tttt ooo');

select regexp_replace(c,'(.*)\|([^|-]*)-[^|]*','\1|\2-') from t;
```

gives

```
sadsa|dd|g - g|hh|yyyyy -
sadsa|dd|g - g|hh|yyyyy - tttt | -
sad -sa|dd|g -|hh|yy yyy tttt ooo
```

see

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45eb2f/1

Comment: it's working but if c is 'sad -sa|dd|g - g|hh|yy  yyy  tttt  ooo'
output will 'sad -sa|dd|g '
instead of 'sad -sa|dd|g - g|hh|yy  yyy  tttt  ooo'

Comment: I've edited my answer.